# Where is the MAP for the LDA RWY 25 at Eagle County Regional

Tags: aeronautical-charts, missed-approach, iap

The MAP for the LDA with GS is the decision altitude. The LDA without GS mins does not have a FAF to MAP distance, nor is timing given.
[image]

Answer (score 4):

The missed approach point for the LDA without GS is CIPKU.  I agree the FAA charts are not as easy to read as the Jeppesen chart.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

As indicated above on the Jeppesen plate, it’s much easier to see where the MAP would be at CIPKU.  Unlike RNAV approach plates, plates using terrestrial navaids do not mark the MAP specifically, but, by default,  use the final waypoint shown on the plate as the MAP.  Another indication would be where waypoint there the approach path changes from a solid line to a dashed line capped with an arrow, indicating the start of the missed approach segment of the procedure.